# Javascript to detect click area within a window and close an element

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys am trying to come up with javascript code thats popularly applied in detecting click area to close an element like a sidenav or a floating div whenever the user clicks outside the element, the click outside works and closes the element but whenever i click inside my element, it still dissappears, here is my code:

```
<script>
    var y = document.getElementById("advert");
    window.onclick = function(event){
        if (event.target == y){
            y.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            y.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: we need more info about your css and html

Comment: Script alone doesn’t tell us much. Please go read [mre], and update your question accordingly. Without seeing the HTML structure, it is impossible to tell if this happens due to event bubbling not handled (resp. interrupted) correctly, or something else.

Comment: The advert is an element is a div that floats at the center of the page on page load

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element second answer is not jquery

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small changes in your code, please try this one:

```
  var y = document.getElementById("advert");
  window.onclick = function(event){
    if (event.target == y || event.target.parentNode == y){
        y.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        y.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Lemme try to add your code to mine and see whether it will work

Comment: Thanks by the way